# Google Tag Manager fires tags in preview/debug, but not on the live site

Tags: json, schema, google-tag-manager

I've used GTM numerous times to fire LD-JSON business schema via a custom-html tag with Tag Manager.  This time however, I'm running into issues.

The tags fire in the debug/preview mode of GTM, but when I publish it they are not found on the live site.  Tag assistant shows no issues with the installation; I should add the custom HTML doesn't appear on the debug/preview, but the tag does fire (per the debugger).

The site in question uses WP-engine, but I've been told that's not likely the issue.  If anyone can point me in a direction that would be great.

I posted on the product forums for google: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/tag-manager/RfxZcqbWrSg/wAWzn98TCwAJ

Comment: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/add-load-listener-script-elements/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was GTM was using the 'document.write' feature for the custom HTML container (which housed the LD-JSON Schema).  Removing that feature populated the site where Google could read the schema.

Props to Simo for being a 'sweet dude' for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to mention that I was having this problem also, and being new to adding custom HTML / JavaScript to my website through Google Tag Manager, I was completely oblivious to the fact that you must click the submit button in the top right of one of the main views (Overview, Tags, Triggers, etc.) in order to publish your changes. I was thinking that the save button within the trigger or tag was all that was needed.(Be sure that you are not forgetting this simple step!).

[image: Submit Button to Publish on Google Tag Manager]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced one similar issue, and for me it was how google tag manager file was served from the app.

It was being served as 
`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/.js?id=yourGtmId`
instead of 
`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=yourGtmId`

Although in the preview mode, the correct file was being served somehow!